# How to use TensorFlow Datasets to get pairs of Omniglot data

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset

I am working with the omniglot dataset which has a structure

```
 Omniglot
    ||______
    |       |
 class_0 class_1    ...           class_N
    |       |_______...______________|
    |              |                 |
class_0 examples  class_1 examples  class_n examples
```

I am trying to use the tensorflow datasets to get pairs of examples and label them 0 if they come from the same examples folder and 1 if they come from different examples folder.

When I execute
'''
omni_train = tfds.load(name="omniglot", split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)
omni_example, = omni_train.take(1)
'''

I get as an output

```
<TakeDataset shapes: {image: (105, 105, 3), alphabet: (), alphabet_char_id: (), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, alphabet: tf.int64, alphabet_char_id: tf.int64, label: tf.int64}>
```

Which I understand, but is there away I can modify this to so that It generates random pairs instead?

It has the alphabet and the alphabet_char_id which means its probably a simple mapping to just if the alphabet and alphabet char id match for the pairs so the label is then a 0 or a 1 and not the nth character in the set as it currently is.

My goal is pass the pair and the label through a siamese neural net that I have already written.

Answer (score 0):

I just dump it into numpy, then write a generator based on it, hope this gist could help somehow.
 https://gist.github.com/chychen/c8249b38cce94ae6a641260b81b23f78